# First item of each list appended to another list in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I can't seem to do the above.

```
---
...
  vars:
    sg:
      - hostname: test26081
        skip: this1
      - hostname: test26082
        skip: this2

    - set_fact:
        sg_dest: "{{ sg[0]['hostname'] }}"
```

My above solution will only append the first hostname (test26081) to my set_fact, I want to include the second hostname test26082 so that I have a plain list of hostnames only. I've tried various things to no avail.

I can't hardcode the second value `"{{ sg[1]['hostname'] }}"` because it needs to scale for new entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over your list `sg` with in the `set_fact` task and append it to an new list (`sg_dest`).

```
--- 
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    sg:
    - hostname: test26081
      skip: this1
    - hostname: test26082
      skip: this2
  tasks: 
  - debug: var=sg
  - name: Initialize an empty list for our hostnames
    set_fact:
      sg_dest: []
  - set_fact:
      sg_dest: "{{ sg_dest + [ item.hostname ] }}"
    with_items: "{{ sg }}"
  - debug: var=sg_dest
```

Comment: Thanks CLNRMN. I was just thinking of doing it this way but my syntax was incorrect, after reading your comment I fixed it and it works now. Thanks for the input.